# como somar valores de registros diferentes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

estou tentando somar o **valor** do **id 1** e o **valor2 do id 2** que no caso seria igual a 220, como faço essa consulta?

```
       ID      VALOR     VALOR2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        110        100
         2        100        110
```

esse era o select que eu estava tentando, mas nao da certo

```
select valor+valor2 from teste3 where valor = (select valor from teste3 where id = 1 and valor2 = (select valor2 from teste3 where id = 2))
```

Comment: é o valor do ID 1 + VALOR2 do ID 2,
no caso 110+110

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql      use a OVER()

Comment: Não entendi o que você precisa , um total acumulado ? um total geral ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(x.valor) AS total
  FROM (
    SELECT valor FROM teste3 WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valor2 FROM teste3 WHERE id = 2
  ) x;
```

Comment: haha, deu certo, nem passo pela minha cabeça usar o union, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Cuidado com o uso do UNION aqui, se as colunas VALOR e VALOR2 tiverem o mesmo valor, o resultado não será correcto.

Comment: @bruno Porquê ?

Comment: @ramaral porque o UNION faz o mesmo trabalho no DISTINCT mostrando só uma vez registros com valores iguais